# How can I import a JSON file on Next.js on build?

Tags: json, next.js

I just want to do a simple thing: **import a JSON file and read it within a function to return some specific data of it**, but it's been really hard to do.

**When on dev env, it works perfectly, but when I try to do the build, the file is not fount**. It's like it's not being imported. Since I'm new with Next.JS architecture, I'm not able to find a solution by myself (read a lot of pages with help, but no success).

**structure**

```
- root
  - config
    - labels
      data.json
      index.ts
```

**index.ts**

```
import data from './data.json';

export type HomeLabels = typeof data.in.home;
export function getHomeLabels(language: string): HomeLabels {

    return data[language as keyof typeof data].home;

}
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "in":{
        "home":{
            "contact_button": "Contact",
            "view_all_button": "View all"
        }
    },
    "pt-br":{
        "home":{
            "contact_button": "Contato",
            "view_all_button": "Ver tudo"
        }
    }   
}
```

**error on build**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'home')
    at getHomeLabels (/home/runner/work/boutme/boutme/.next/server/chunks/261.js:42:43)
```

All the solutions that I found out was related to using API or `getStaticsProps` and using on component. But I really don't want it. I think that it's possible to do what I want (import json and read just on a function), but it's been hard.

Comment: @SeanW - I followed your idea that the JSON was already imported and could solve the problem. It's seems that the language param. at some moment on build was undefined. Since I'm new with Next.Js, do you know what could it be? would be great to understand it. Because on dev end it was working perfectly. 

To solve it I just added a default value for language param. `language: string = 'pt-br'`

Comment: How do you get or how is your lang param set? Is it a function call, is it an async function call, is it a page prop etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you dont want to use getStaticsProps/api. You might need to change your import statement like this, and try to read the file inside the function

import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

export function getHomeLabels(language: string): any {
   const data = await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + './data.json', 'utf8');
    return data[language as keyof typeof data].home;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).